# Get image clicked element with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to be able to get ANY element's html code when I click on it.
So far I can only get text elements but I can't get image elements.
Here's what I have :

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    alert($(event.target).html());      
});
```

this doesn't work with images tags like 
`<img src="" alt=""/>`
but only with text ..
Can you please tell me how to proceed to get the images element ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Self closing elements don't contain any HTML ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html

Comment: Yeah.. That's what I just figured out.

Comment: I am guessing you just didn't know what it was called. That is literally the first google search result.

Comment: Yes, I was googling for 20 minutes about getting img element's html didn't find any good answers

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.outerHTML) as fields like image/input(self closing) does not contain html

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    alert(event.target.outerHTML);      
});
```